r - ANOVA on a distance matrix (nesting required?)
I have an experimental design intended to investigate the influence of two treatment factors (A with 2 levels and B with 8 levels) on the proportions in 8 groups. However, due to technical reasons, I do not have the proportions in the 8 groups, but only a Bray-Curtis dissimilarity matrix. Now, I want to find out whether the two factors A & B, as well as their interaction (A*B), influence the dissimilarity (Y).
How can I best analyze this design with R? I thought about converting the dissimilarity matrix back into a long format, where I would note the two factor levels as A.1 and A.2, and B.1 and B.2, respectively. Then, I could nest A.2 within A.1 and B.2 within B.1 to check whether the factors have a significant influence. Is this consideration correct? In R, it would look like this:
aov(Y ~ A.1/A.2 * B.1/B.2)

Is this correct? Can I really test what I'm interested in (main effects and interaction) with this? Or could you recommend a more straight-forward approach? Thanks a lot in advance!

Well, one possible solution seems to be to use a PERMANOVA (as implemented in the 'vegan' package) instead:
adonis2(dist.matrix ~ A.1 * B.1)

